# facelet debug mode not working

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have this entry in web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Tried Ctrl+Shift+D to open debug mode but didn't work and bookmarking for my browser gets opened.

So put a page level debug.

```
<ui:debug hotkey="z" rendered="true" />
```

The debug results now opens in another window but doesn't load component tree information (scoped variables are displayed though).

Comment: Which version of jsf you are using ?

Comment: jsf 1.2 sun implementation

Comment: Which Facelets version are you using? You're not terribly clear on problem description, but a similar bug was fixed in 1.1.15: http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-292 (this DID load the component tree information, it is also just visible in generated HTML output, but it was simply not expandable due to a JS issue in expand button).

Comment: much better go with the latest ... it's just a suggestion

Comment: facelets version is 1.1.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *facelets version is 1.1.14*

You're not terribly clear on problem description, but a similar bug was fixed in 1.1.15 as per [issue 292](http://java.net/jira/browse/FACELETS-292). Please note that the debug window **did** load the component tree information (it's just visible in generated HTML output by rightclick and *View Source*), but it was simply not expandable due to a JS issue in expand button.

Just upgrade to Facelets 1.1.15. It's also the latest Facelets 1.x version. You can download it [here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/com/sun/facelets/jsf-facelets/1.1.15/jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar).